# How to replace values with substrings in pandas objects?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have coordinates in a Latitude dataset that each end with a letter (ex. N).

What is the best way to retrieve only the numbers and replace the original values?

My attempt at this was:

```
raw['LATITUDE'] = raw.loc[(raw['LATITUDE'].str.len() == 9)].str[0:8]
```

But I get an AttributeError message.

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I also tried replacing the values with regex but I wasn't sure how to make it successful.

I'd appreciate any suggestions, thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, let's clarify a couple of things:

1. You seem to be working with mixed dtypes. Print out `raw['LATITUDE'].apply(type).nunique()` to confirm; it should be > 1.
2. You're working with geodata. A lot of your values are invalid (the 0s), which I'd recommend be coerced to NaNs instead because that represents missing data more meaningfully

To fix your issue, try getting everything upto the last character (`:-1`):

```
raw['LATITUDE'] = raw['LATITUDE'].str[:-1].astype(float)
raw

   LATITUDE
0       NaN
1  38.72496
2  39.90272
3  38.72927
4  39.91152
5  39.84841
6       NaN
7       NaN
8       NaN
9  39.84941
```

This works *despite* your column being of mixed dtypes, because the `str` accessor is designed to coerce non-string rows to NaN.

If you wish to preserve 0s (which I don't recommend), use a fast replacement function like `np.where`;

```
raw['LATITUDE'] = np.where(
    raw.LATITUDE.eq(0), 0, raw['LATITUDE'].str[:-1].astype(float)
)

raw
   LATITUDE
0   0.00000
1  38.72496
2  39.90272
3  38.72927
4  39.91152
5  39.84841
6   0.00000
7   0.00000
8   0.00000
9  39.84941
```

The reason I don't recommend preserving the 0s is because it is semantically more meaningful to use NaN to demarcate missing data instead of 0.

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation was straightforward, simple, and it worked. After reading your suggestion I'd rather get rid of all the rows that have NaN. How would you recommend going about that?

Comment: @elbertkim You may simply do something along the lines of `raw = raw.dropna(subset=['LATITUDE'])`. If you want to drop every row with NaNs regardless, go for `raw = raw.dropna()`. And you're welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

You appear to have mixed types in your series with dtype `object`.

**Option 1**

You can first attempt to convert to numeric with `errors='coerce'`, and then `fillna` with all up to the last character prior to converting to `float`:

```
s = pd.Series(['34.49881N', 0], dtype=object)

s = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').fillna(s.str[:-1].astype(float))
```

**Option 2**

You can also work the other way round. This is inadvisable as it is less stringent, i.e. you may find unexpected types in the result.

```
s = s.str[:-1].astype(float).fillna(s)
```

**Result**

In both cases, you will find:

```
print(s)

0    34.49881
1     0.00000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is virtually my answer but with unnecessary fluff. Option 1 is doing more things than it needs to, and Option 2 is pretty much the same thing I've already written.

Comment: I disagree. Test your solution with `s = pd.Series(['34.49881N', 0], dtype=object)`. It doesn't work.

Comment: Non-string items in mixed object columns are implicitly casted to NaN, this simplifies a lot of things. I assume OP just wants the latitudes and nothing else. I'd suggest leaving those NaNs to begin with.

Comment: `s.str[:-1].astype(float)` works, and that's all that needs to work, really. I don't understand what you mean by "not work"... if you mean it's the zeros that disappear, then yeah, those will become NaNs, as they should

Comment: I appreciate your point of view. But I'll let OP decide on what he wants. It's not clear in the question, and either of our assumptions may be incorrect.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, No worries, I've been here long enough to know the gang :).

Comment: Ya know, I dislike downvotes without comments. I've compensated it for you, enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `where`

```
df.LATITUDE.where(df['LATITUDE'].str.len() == 9,df.LATITUDE.str[0:8])
Out[956]: 
0           0
1    38.72496
2    39.90272
3    38.72927
4    39.91152
5    39.84841
6           0
7           0
8           0
9    39.84941
Name: LATITUDE, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are confident that your data will always only include one hemisphere (no southern latitudes), I do not recommend the substring approach, since it will convert both (for example) 39.2342N and 39.2342S to the same value.

Instead, I would use a `map` to convert the string to a number with a sign reflecting the hemisphere:

```
df['Fixed_Lat'] = df['LATITUDE'].map(lambda x: -float(x[:-1]) if x[-1] == 'S' else float(x[:-1]))
```